# php outputs code after trying to call a method

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am trying to recreate the laravel eloquent ORM.
after i try to call a method of a class, php prints the code which is behind the call. I work with composer and namespaces. Maybe it is important to know that i use xampp?!

Here is my Code

**index.php**

```
<?
namespace com;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


use com\config\Conf;
use com\db\Table;
use com\db\dataTypes\INTEGER;
use com\Connectors\MySqlConnector;

$DB_HOST = Conf::$DB_HOST;
$DB_PORT = Conf::$DB_PORT;
$DB_USER = Conf::$DB_USER;
$DB_PASSWORD = Conf::$DB_PASSWORD;
$DB_NAME = Conf::$DB_NAME;

$connector = new MySqlConnector($DB_HOST,$DB_PORT,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME);

$t1 = new Table("table1");
$age = new INTEGER("age");

//affected call
$age = $age -> primary() -> unsigned();


$counting = new INTEGER("counting");
$counting = $counting->nullable(false)->defaultValue(18);
$t1->addData($age);
$t1->addData($counting);

$connector->addTable($t1);
$connector->registerTables();
```

I have marked the part of the code with "//affected call".

**INTEGER.php**

```
<?
namespace com\db\dataTypes;

use com\db\dataTypes\DataType;
use com\config\Conf;

class INTEGER extends DataType{

    
    private int $defaultValue = 0;
    private bool $unsigned = false;

    function __construct(string $col) {
        $this->column = $col;
    }
    //code

    public function primary() : INTEGER {
        $this->isPrimaryKey = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function unsigned() : INTEGER {
        $this->unsigned = true;
        return $this;
    }
    //code
}
```

The output looks like that

```
primary() -> unsigned(); $counting = new INTEGER("counting"); $counting = $counting->nullable(false)->defaultValue(18); $t1->addData($age); $t1->addData($counting); $connector->addTable($t1); $connector->registerTables();
```

I don't know if it helps but here is my **composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "com\\": "",
            "com\\config\\": "config/",
            "com\\db\\": "db/",
            "com\\db\\dataTypes\\": "db/dataTypes/",
            "com\\Connectors\\": "Connectors/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? You can use Eloquent without Laravel if you want to, they are not attached at the hip :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am doing this for fun. so there is no reason. I know I can us Eloquent without Laravel but I want to do it myself

Comment: are you sure that there si no erro in the server log?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes, there is no error. I am using XAMMP maybe this changes something

Comment: What is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work? How is this related to [tag:namespaces] or [tag:composer-php]?

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is that php Outputs code after trying to call a function. And I don't know why it isn't working so thought it is maybe because of me using namespaces.